# Solving the equation of damped oscillator

Tags: complex-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, physics

I'm asked to prove that any solution of the equation $$\ddot\Phi+\Gamma\dot\Phi+\omega_0^2\Phi=0;\qquad \omega_0>\frac\Gamma 2$$ is $$\Phi=A_0e^{-\frac{\Gamma}{2} t}e^{i(\omega t-\beta)};\qquad \omega^2\equiv\omega_0 ^2-\left(\frac{\Gamma}2\right)^2$$
maybe show is simple, but I would get the process of obtaining the solution, many thanks in advance.

Comment: The $\forall \omega$ bit should be removed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $x=(\Phi, \dot{\Phi})^T$. Then the equation becomes
$\dot{x}(t) =  A x(t)$, where $A= \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ -\omega_0^2 & -\Gamma \end{bmatrix} $ which has the solution $x(t) = e^{At} x_0$.

The eigenvalues of $A$ are given by solutions to $\lambda(\lambda+\Gamma) + \omega_0^2 = 0$, which are
$\lambda = {1 \over 2} (-\Gamma \pm \sqrt{\Gamma^2-4 \omega_0^2}) ={1 \over 2} (-\Gamma \pm i\sqrt{4 \omega_0^2-\Gamma^2}) =-{ 1\over 2} \Gamma \pm i \sqrt{\omega_0^2-({\Gamma \over 2})^2} = -{ 1\over 2} \Gamma \pm i \omega$.

Since the eigenvalues are distinct, $A$ is diagonalisable and can be written as
$A= V \begin{bmatrix} -{ 1\over 2} \Gamma + i \omega & 0 \\ 0 & -{ 1\over 2} \Gamma - i \omega  \end{bmatrix} V^{-1}$, and so $e^{At} = V \begin{bmatrix} e^{(-{ 1\over 2} \Gamma + i \omega)t} & 0 \\ 0 & e^{(-{ 1\over 2} \Gamma - i \omega)t}  \end{bmatrix} V^{-1}$.

Hence the general solution is given by
$\Phi(t) = c_+ e^{(-{ 1\over 2} \Gamma + i \omega)t} + c_- e^{(-{ 1\over 2} \Gamma - i \omega)t}$ for some constants $c_+,c_-$.

Comment: Okay it's so interesting! hey! It's too much trouble if I ask by the phase?

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking. The general solution is given above, note that this is a more general solution that you have in the question (set $c_+=A_0 e^{-i \beta}$) as there is also the $t \mapsto c_- e^{(-{ 1\over 2} \Gamma - i \omega)t}$ solution.